# Finding the tangent to a point on the curve

Tags: derivatives, curves, tangent-line

I was able to figure out the answer to the following question but I didn't understand how the process worked.

Question:

*The tangent at the point P on the curve $ y=x^2+1 $   passes through the origin. Find the equation to the tangent.*

My first impression was to find the gradient of the tangent by finding the derivative of the curve.

$\frac{dy}{dx}= 2x
$

I let the point P =  a,b

p(a,b)

Hence

$\frac{dy}{dx}= 2a
$

I then constructed the equation of the tangent.

$y=(2a)x+c $

I know $C=0$ as the tangent passes through (0,0)

Hence

$y=(2a)x$

I found the derivative ( I don't understand why) of $\frac{dy}{dx}= 2a
$ to give the gradient of 2 completing the equation of the tangent to the curve:

$y=2x+c $

My question is how does finding the second derivative of the curve result in the gradient of the tangent?

Comment: You are on the right track as far as $y=2ax$. Then you wander off. You have the equation of the tangent. Use that and the equation of the curve to find the value of $a$.

Comment: Why you need second derivative? Your work is good you now need to find the coordinates a,b following the hints. What else is not clear in the process?

Comment: @gimusi When I found the second derivative, it got me the gradient of the tangent. I was wondering why this is

Comment: In this case the gradient is the derivative for the curve/parabola $dy/dx=2x$. By this you can argue that fo a point P(a,b) which belongs to the parabola the tangent must have slope 2a. That is precisely the condition you have used to find the equation for the tangent $y=2a x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work is ok, you can now find the point $P(a,b)$ by the fact that it must belongs both to the tangent and to the parabola, notably

$$y=(2a)x \implies b=2a^2$$

and thus

$$y=x^2+1 \implies 2a^2=a^2+1 \implies a=\pm1 \quad b=2$$

Now verify which one is good or if both work.

> By symmetry it easy verify that both values work for $P(\pm 1,2)$ with tangents $y=\pm 2x$.

Answer (score 0):

Note there is a faster way, which shows there are two solutions to this problem.

It amounts to finding the tangents which can be drawn from the origin to the parabola.

Now, a (non-vertical) straight line through the origin has equation $y=tx$ for some $t\in\mathbf R$, and such a line  is tangent to the parabola if and only if the equation for the abscissæ of the intersection points:
$$ tx=x^2+1\iff x^2-tx+1=0 $$
has a *double root, i.e. if and only if the discriminant of this equation:
$ \Delta = t^2-4 \;$ is $0$. This  $t=\pm2$, and rthe equations of the tangent lines from the origin are
$$y=\pm2x. $$
Furthermore, the abscissæ of the points of contact with the parabola are the double roots: $x=\pm 1$.